# Remove all spaces before a specific symbol/character in a text file using notepad++

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

Okay I'm trying to set up a set of tag lists for a translation script but have encountered a problem I need to remove the spaces in one of the languages using regex

the lines are set up like `"JP JP":"ENG ENG"` and I would like it to be `"JPJP":"ENG ENG"`

I'm new when it comes to regex so I'm out of ideas of what to try

Thanks!

Comment: You can use
 (.*)":
to take the space and caracteres
and then replace it with (\1)": without the space

Comment: it could be your first question on SO, it is not clear. You better gave an example input and output. A clearly described question helps you get best answer sooner. 1) `JP JP, ENG ENG` those text should be dynamic aren't they? 2) if you just want to do replacement on `".. ..":".. .."` pattern? not `"..."` (without the colon part) 3) could there be more than one spaces in your pattern? e.g. `"DE ein gutes Buch":"ENG a good book"`? 4) in title of question you said "using notepad++", it would be good add a same tag, so that you could get the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this expression uses positive lookahead

```
\s+(?=\w+":")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Unix` utility `sed`

```
sed -i 's/old_name/new_name/g' your-file
```

In your example this should be:

```
sed -i 's/"JP JP":"ENG ENG"/"JPJP":"ENGENG"/g' your-file
```